# Getting Android enum descriptions to appear in JavaDoc

Tags: android, xml, enums, javadoc

I have defined a custom attribute in xml that must take an `enum` value as a parameter.  The JavaDoc that is automatically produced from my application's `R.attr` builds a table with `enum` name and value, but filling in the description column eludes me.  How do I define a description that will appear in the JavaDoc?

An example attribute with `enum` constants:

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="directions">
        <enum name="up" value="0" />
        <enum name="down" value="1" />
        <enum name="left" value="2" />
        <enum name="right" value="3" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

To show what I mean, the JavaDoc for [`directionPriority`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#directionPriority) in `android.R.attr` has a table for all the possible enums with "constant," "value" and "description" all filled in.

I have done a good deal of research and tried trial-and-error guesses at a tag that might allow me to include a description, but to no avail.  Does anyone know the proper way to document this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add comments before each of the enums.  These comments are automatically translated into the enum description column.

```
<declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
    <attr name="directions">
        <!-- Go up! -->
        <enum name="up" value="0" />
        <!-- Go down! -->
        <enum name="down" value="1" />
        <!-- Go left! -->
        <enum name="left" value="2" />
        <!-- Go right! -->
        <enum name="right" value="3" />
    </attr>
</declare-styleable>
```